SFINAE-kindish function definition BUT without templates
Example
Many consumers of the following class
class A{
   double a;
   void dump(){
      std::ofstream ooo("dump.txt"); ooo << A.a << "\n"; ooo.close();
   }
};

will not use dump and cannot #include<fstream>. How do I make it that A still permits compilation by omission of void dump() in that scenario.
Question
What is the best practice to solving the problem?
Constraints

I do not wish to change the signature of dump.

I cannot use #ifdef unless #include<fstream> will make an according define as per ISO.

A is a parent of many other classes. If I was to specialize from A then all derivatives would need a templatization of inheritance over A, appearing unpreferable.


Attempts
ChatGPT proposes a requirement-dependent definition over the instantiability of std::ofstream; however the definition of either case must remain written, thus causing a compilation error. I also do not see how to overcome the issue, as of my limited understanding of the language, I must at some point specify a definition and definition templates will be instantiated eventually, thus causing an instantiated invalid definition anyways. So I am lacking a piece of grammar or paradigm here, which is what I seek.
Remarks
I encounter it first time, but in interpreted languages it is of course rather the norm than exception that definitions are invalid under most circumstances but those in which they are utilized.

why is dump a member of A when many customers want to use A but cannot use dump ? Thats a flaw in the design that rather than working around you should fix

SFINAE and other things only applies to templated entities. Without them, there is no modern way.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Thanks. I added reasons to the constraints.

sorry, I see the edit but I see no reason to not fix a broken design

"I cannot use #ifdef" - why is that ? It seem like the only way to achieve what you want without changing the design.

@wohlstad Because "#ifdef __FSTREAM" will return false either way, unless ISO commands fstream to define __FSTREAM.

@user23311233 why not use a custom #define ? your customers that would like to use dump will define it, and others will not (#include<fstream> can be under this #ifdef as well).

@user23311233 please do not attack users personally. If you think some comments are inappropriate you can flag them

What do you mean "cannot include fstream"? Is that not available to them? In that case, could you not just use __has_include to check for the header?

"Okay, so you say you have a fix. Show it. " I can't. This is a xy problem. YOu are asking for the workaround, I suggest you to fix the actual issue about which you didnt tell us much (other than you insist on not fixing it).

The solution is extremely simple and meets all requirements. The consumers of the class use the header file:
class A{
   double a;
   void dump() ;
};

You write the .cpp file:
#include <fstream>
void A:: dump()  {
   std::ofstream ooo("dump.txt"); ooo << A.a << "\n"; ooo.close();
}


Header compiles without <fstream>
No templates
No #ifdef
Signature doesn't change (Still missing const though)

The linker takes care of including dump if and when needed.
